# Java Find the color of last bean

Tags: java

I made a method to take out "beans" from a tin (char[] beans). "Beans" are only green or blue, this method is to take out 2 beans. If they are both greens or blues, put 1 blue "bean" back, Else put the green one back. Repeat until there are only 1 "bean" left. But there are sometimes 1 left or even 3 or 4 left. I can't seem to find the solution.The code kinda looks like this

```
public static void takeTwo(int size, char [] beans){ 
    int b1, b2;
    int count = size;
    while (count >= 2){

        int r1 = (int)(Math.random()*size) ;
        int r2 = (int)(Math.random()*size) ;
        b1 = beans[r1];
        b2 = beans[r2];
        beans [r1] = Empty;
        beans [r2] = Empty;

        if (b1 == Green && b2 == Green || b1 == Blue && b2 == Blue){
            int j = (int)(Math.random() *2);
            if (j == 1)
                b1 = Blue;
            else 
                b2 = Blue;
        }
        else if (b1 == Green && b2 == Blue){
            b1 = Green;
        }
        else if (b1 == Blue && b2 == Green){
            b2 = Green;
        }
        count = count-1;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please explain the problem more clearly,w hat are you exactly trying to do...are all beans only blue green.. ?

Comment: also if you taking out beans and putting them back.. how will the left over beans size be any diff ?

Comment: Sorry it was hard to explain. "Beans" are only green or blue, this method is to take out 2 beans. If they are both greens or blues, put 1 blue back, Else put the green one back. Repeat until there are only 1 "bean" left

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my understanding I am repeating your problem in my words.

You pass an array of characters named `beans`. You also pass the size of the array as variable `size`. If the size of the array is greater than or equal to 2 your take randomly 2 character values from the array and store them in 2 variables `b1` and `b2`. Now you set the values of the array from where you have taken the variables to `EMPTY` or `null`. Now when you have b1 and b2 same then you put back `BLUE` else you put back one `GREEN`. You continue doing this till you are left with the array beans of size = 1.

If this is correct, then I would like to point out to you certain problems that I saw in your code.

Firstly when you are randomly selecting the position in the array beans, It might result to you having variables r1 and r2 being same. In other words if you have say size = 2, the generation of random numbers might result to r1 being 1 and r2 being 1. So, what results is b1 and b2 having same values.

Secondly you have not written any code to discard the values taken out from the array. What I mean to say is you are setting the values in the array to Empty or what I may say to `null`. But the location in the array still exists. Let me give an example: Say your array beans has a size of 10. The random number generated gave values say 1 and 2. Now after removing the beans you have `beans[1] = null; beans[2] = null;` after the loop has completed in the next iteration of the loop, the random number generator can generate values 1 and 2 and that will result in b1 and/or b2 being Empty or `null`. Which then results to a situation where this variables attain a value that is not expected to attain.

And Finally, I did not find any line in your code by which you have put back the selected value to the original array beans.

So I would suggest that you go through the problems that I have stated here and again try freshly code the program.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that when you set a chosen bean to "Empty", your if-else ladder doesn't decide how to handle it. So, edit your code so that when an "Empty" is chosen, the variable `count` is not decremented.
Example:

```
if (b1 == Green && b2 == Green || b1 == Blue && b2 == Blue){
//some code in here
}else if(b1 == Empty || b2 == Empty){ 
    continue; //this will stop the loop from decreasing variable count
}
count = count - 1;
```

This means that an "Empty" will not count as a bean chosen, as it already has been chosen. Also, when your "putting the bean back into the tin" you have to set the actual array value to Blue or Green. For example, instead of `b1 = Blue` on line 14, you should do:

```
beans[r1] = Blue;
```

This might be another bug that is causing a problem.

Comment: If I did that, the loop wouldn't stop for some reason, it would keep running even if there are 1 "bean" left or the "beans" are all Empty

Comment: @tunglam264 Sorry if I am being rude, but are you going to pick an accepted answer? Sorry for the interruption.